# Cannot find module './clone.js'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I installed angular cli via terminal. When I try to use ng(to create a new project), I get an error: Cannot find module './clone.js'[terminal snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB7Fy.png)
I've tried to delete angular and clear cache, but that didn't help. Can somebody come up with solution, please?

Comment: You need to add a project name, e.g. `ng new app`; though do not create your project within the directory _system32_.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. The problem appears to be with graceful-fs 4.1.12: it requires './clone.js' but that file didn't end up in the package :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graceful-fs, which is depended on by a LOT of npm packages, just released 4.1.12, which has a bug in it: https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading to the new version of angular

```
ng update
```